# Texmaker using old version of Texlive

Tags: texlive, texmaker

I have just installed texlive2021, where I was previously using texlive2017. I'm now trying to change it so that texmaker will compile using the new version, but everything I've tried still gives me the message

> This is pdfTeX, version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (Tex Live 2017/Debian) ...

I have tried adding the following lines

```
PATH=/home/steven/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/home/steven/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/home/steven/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

to

```
~/.profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
/.bashrc
```

and none of them seem to change my output message to 2021. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to do a hard restart of my machine for this to take place (that is a pain as I have unsaved ipython work)? Do I need to change something in Texmaker?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Let me guess you start texmaker using a menu, short cut or by double clicking on a `.tex` file?

Comment: In that case it is not enough to add the path change to `bashrc` it needs to go into `.profile` as well and then you need to log out and in again as `.profile` is only read at login. Unless you start `texmaker` from the command line, no `bash` is involved and so any setting in `.bashrc` is never applied to the `texmaker` process.

Comment: (this is sadly a very common error)

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't explicitely stated in the manual. Thanks @daleif. Would you please reply to my thread with an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Precicely which manual have you been looking in?

Comment: I'd actually say that this is a duplicate (as I've answered this several times), but cannot find a suitable candidate to mark this as a duplicate of

Comment: I couldn't pull anything up on this either, at least nothing that solved my issue, or was explicit in it's explanation of starting texmaker from an icon instead of the terminal was causing the issue. I had already read somewhere I needed to change ```~/.profile``` instead of ```~/.bashrc``` but it was the restart I needed.
Edit: I was starting texmaker from a saved session which opens several of my files for my thesis into one session.

Comment: I was using the quick install guide https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

and the full installation guide (3.4.1 in particular) https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable

Comment: restart isn't actually needed, just a re-login

Comment: There are nothing about bashrc on any of those pages. But they ought to mention that to need to re-login

Comment: No it doesn't however it does say adding to bath, and I've only ever done that in bashrc before. Granted that is a lack of understanding on my part, but it could have been more explicit. The quick guide doesn't mention the ```~/.profile``` file either, so as I was primarily using the quick guide, bashrc was my starting point.
Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: I mispoke but `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH ` this prepends to `PATH`. https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-300003.4.1 does mention the `profile`. The installation "of course" assumes that you know what you are doing, you are a Linux user after all. One should probably be more specific instead.

Comment: I now know it is in ```~/.profile```, and when I posted my question I had the line in ```~/.profile``` only, I'd removed it from both the bash options, it was just the re-login I hadn't yet done.
I'm not a fan of the assuming people know what they're talking about just because I'm using Linux. I was using Ubuntu for a few years before I learned what bash is. I only learn more about Linux when trying to do things for the first time and they don't work. IMO the quick guide should mention the specific file, and the long guide should mention the re-login for this common error.

Comment: That is exactly my point. In the old days, you only used Linux if you knew what you were doing. Today it is more mainstream and things like this needs to be more specific

Comment: Ah I see. I completely agree! Perhaps I'll try and contact the developers to put this note in their documents. Thanks again.